# How do I get the data from a callback function in Matlab for further processing?

Tags: matlab, function, callback, udp

I am trying to get 16000 values/second in MatLab from an UDP socket by using a callback function.

This kind of works for now but I don't know how to get the values of the received packages for further post processing (e.g. write them to SQL DB/plot them), as the variables are only local ones and not written to my workspace?

The code I'm using at the moment:

```
%% Specify a Server (host name or IP address) with Port 8080
u = udp('192.168.0.164', 8080);  %UDP Object


u.InputBufferSize = 1024;
u.ReadAsyncMode = 'continuous';
u.DatagramReceivedFcn = @DatagramReceivedFcn;
u.DatagramTerminateMode = 'on';
u.Terminator = '!';

%% Oeffnen der Verbindung
fopen(u);

 if (~strcmp(u.Status,'open'))
     NetworkError(u,'Connection failed!');
 end


%% Start Data transmission by trigger
fprintf(u, 'Requesting Data')


%% Callback Funktion
function DatagramReceivedFcn(u,~) 
    %avail = u.BytesAvailable;
    datagram = fscanf(u);
    disp('Data Received!');
    disp(datagram);

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a nested function that acts as a "closure" here! Create a variable to use as a buffer outside your function and then reference/assign to that inside your nested `DatagramReceivedFcn` function.

For this to work, the whole rest of your code will have to be in a function itself.

```
function DoTheThing

%% Specify a Server (host name or IP address) with Port 8080
u = udp('192.168.0.164', 8080);  %UDP Object

% Here's your buffer in the enclosing function
myBuffer = {};

u.InputBufferSize = 1024;
u.ReadAsyncMode = 'continuous';
u.DatagramReceivedFcn = @DatagramReceivedFcn;

% [...]

%% Start Data transmission by trigger
fprintf(u, 'Requesting Data')


%% Callback Function
function DatagramReceivedFcn(u,~) 
    %avail = u.BytesAvailable;
    datagram = fscanf(u);
    disp('Data Received!');
    disp(datagram);
    myBuffer{end+1} = datagram;  % References myBuffer in the enclosing function!
end

end
```

And it would probably be more readable if you moved the callback function up to be next to the `myBuffer` initialization.

Comment: Thank you very much - this might help me a lot!

As a follow up question: Could you give me a hint maybe on how to access the buffer data for further processing?

What I would like to do is, while receiving the datagrams, I would like to store them in a FIFO-Buffer (Think I am able to adjust "myBuffer" to FIFO) and simultaneously write the Buffer-Data to a SQL DB and also plot it.

Do you think using different functions in parfor loops will suit my needs to achieve this target or is there a better/correct way to do this?